# Caesar Cypher Without Using ord() and chr()

Tags: python

I am trying if there is an easier way to encrpyt and decrpyt text using caesar cipher  and especially without using chr() or ord() while still using Object-oriented programming. This looks very chatGPT based.

```
class Caesar():
    def __init__(self, text, key):
        self.text = text
        self.key = key
    
def encrypt(self):
    encrypted_text = ""
    for char in self.text:
        if char.isalpha():
            shifted_char = chr((ord(char) - ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A') + self.key) % 26 + ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A'))
            encrypted_text += shifted_char
        else:
            encrypted_text += char
    return encrypted_text

def decrypt(self):
    decrypted_text = ""
    for char in self.text:
        if char.isalpha():
            shifted_char = chr((ord(char) - ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A') - self.key) % 26 + ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A'))
            decrypted_text += shifted_char
        else:
            decrypted_text += char
    return decrypted_text
```

main program

```
               choice = input("Enter 'E' for encrypt or 'D' for decrypt: ")
            if choice.upper() == 'E':
                plaintext = input("Please type the text you want to encrypt: ")
                key = int(input("Enter the cipher key: "))
                cipher = Caesar(plaintext, key)
                encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt()
                print("Ciphertext:", encrypted_text)
            elif choice.upper() == 'D':
                ciphertext = input("Please type the text you want to decrypt: ")
                key = int(input("Enter the cipher key: "))
                cipher = Caesar(ciphertext, key)
                decrypted_text = cipher.decrypt()
                print("Decrypted text:", decrypted_text)
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'E' or 'D'.")
```

Output intended:

[image]

[image]

Also for error handling, i tried cipher key = 26, not sure if this outcome is correct.

[image]

I am trying if there is an easier way to encrpyt and decrpyt text using caesar cipher and especially without using chr() or ord() while still using Object-oriented programming. This looks very chatGPT based

```
class Caesar():
    def __init__(self, text, key):
        self.text = text
        self.key = key

def encrypt(self):
    encrypted_text = ""
    for char in self.text:
        if char.isalpha():
            shifted_char = chr((ord(char) - ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A') + self.key) % 26 + ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A'))
            encrypted_text += shifted_char
        else:
            encrypted_text += char
    return encrypted_text

def decrypt(self):
    decrypted_text = ""
    for char in self.text:
        if char.isalpha():
            shifted_char = chr((ord(char) - ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A') - self.key) % 26 + ord('a' if char.islower() else 'A'))
            decrypted_text += shifted_char
        else:
            decrypted_text += char
    return decrypted_text
```

main program

```
   choice = input("Enter 'E' for encrypt or 'D' for decrypt: ")
            if choice.upper() == 'E':
                plaintext = input("Please type the text you want to encrypt: ")
                key = int(input("Enter the cipher key: "))
                cipher = Caesar(plaintext, key)
                encrypted_text = cipher.encrypt()
                print("Ciphertext:", encrypted_text)
            elif choice.upper() == 'D':
                ciphertext = input("Please type the text you want to decrypt: ")
                key = int(input("Enter the cipher key: "))
                cipher = Caesar(ciphertext, key)
                decrypted_text = cipher.decrypt()
                print("Decrypted text:", decrypted_text)
            else:
                print("Invalid choice. Please enter 'E' or 'D'.")
```

Output intended:

My intuition tells me that this class should not accept a text parameter, just a key parameter and that your encrypt method should be passed the text.

Comment: @JonSG please take a look

Comment: `This looks very chatGPT based` What do you mean? Did you write this code? If ChatGPT wrote this code, it's not okay to ask us to debug it, especially without it being totally clear that you didn't write it, if that's indeed the case.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach the problem. I would create a class that accepts the key as a parameter and then build the class with methods that accept messages to encrypt or decrypt with the given key.

You mentioned not wanting to use `chr()` and `ord()` so this solution is based on python's `str.translate()` and it's related `str.maketrans()`

Note that one of the interesting quirks of a rotational cypher is that the key to decrypt is the negative of the key to encrypt. Other than that, encryption and decryption are the same process.

```py
import string

class Caesar():
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = key
    
    def encrypt(self, msg):
        return Caesar._crypt(self.key, msg)

    def decrypt(self, msg):
        return Caesar._crypt(-self.key, msg)

    ## -----------------------
    ## Decryption via a Ceasar rotation is the same as
    ## encryption with a negative version of the key
    ## -----------------------
    @staticmethod
    def _crypt(key, msg):
        from_chars = string.printable[:-2]                  ## The last 2 characters are funky
        key = key % len(from_chars)                         ## make sure our key is in a valid range
        to_chars = from_chars[key:] + from_chars[:key]      ## rotate the letters by the key
        return msg.translate(str.maketrans(from_chars, to_chars))
    ## -----------------------

caesar = Caesar(26)

msg = "The Quick Brown Fox"
msg_encrypted = caesar.encrypt(msg)
msg_decrypted = caesar.decrypt(msg_encrypted)

print(f"Original Message : \"{ msg }\"")
print(f"Encrypted Message: \"{ msg_encrypted }\"")
print(f"Decrypted Message: \"{ msg_decrypted }\"")
```

That should give you:

```
Original Message : "The Quick Brown Fox"
Encrypted Message: ">HEm;UICKm"ROWNm&OX"
Decrypted Message: "The Quick Brown Fox"
```

**Addendum:**

To produce an identical output to your code, there are is one change to make. My code acts on all printable characters while your code acts on lowercase letters and uppercase letters rotating within the bounds of each set of letters. That is, lowercase letters rotate to lowercase letters and uppercase to uppercase. Let's fix mine so that it works likes yours.

```py
    def _crypt(key, msg):
        key = key % len(string.ascii_lowercase)
        from_chars = string.ascii_lowercase + string.ascii_uppercase
        to_chars = string.ascii_lowercase[key:] + string.ascii_lowercase[:key] + string.ascii_uppercase[key:] + string.ascii_uppercase[:key]
        return msg.translate(str.maketrans(from_chars, to_chars))
```

Then using your message and key we get:

```
Original Message : "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG"
Encrypted Message: "QEB NRFZH YOLTK CLU GRJMP LSBO QEB IXWV ALD"
Decrypted Message: "THE QUICK BROWN FOX JUMPS OVER THE LAZY DOG"
```

Comment: Alternatively you could've done `maketrans(from_chars + from_chars.lower(), to_chars + to_chars.lower())`. Which seems slightly less annoying :-). If only there were a flag for case-insensitivity...

Comment: @JonSG, Thanks so much. Can i ask if you are able to solve the other question I posted.

Comment: I might be able to. What was the other question? Is it part of this post or a second post?

Comment: @JonSG But i tried using the second block of code but it dosent work on small-letters:

The QUICK BROWN fox jumps over the lazy dog

Enter the cipher key: -3

Plaintext:       The QUICK BROWN fox jumps over the lazy dog
Ciphertext:      Qhe NRFZH YOLTK fox jumps over the lazy dog

Comment: You might want to check again. With the final version `_crypt(key, msg)` in the update, I see the message : *"The QUICK BROWN fox jumps over the lazy dog"* encrypts to *"Qeb NRFZH YOLTK clu grjmp lsbo qeb ixwv ald"*. Note I made several updates so be suer to get the lastest version.

Comment: @JonSG Oh yes, the question Is another question i posted. Thanks